# EOF caught while checking if connected

Tags: phpmailer

I would like to send an email from localhost by using PHP Mailer.
i have already look for others question and that solve some of the error that i got.
Except for this last error.i did not find the answer that fit to solve the error. I am really hope for help to solve this error.

This is what being diplayed after try to run the code.

> 2018-08-03 04:57:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
>   2018-08-03 04:57:44 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
>   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
>   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
>   Email could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

This is my code

```
<html>
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'username@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('test@gmail.com', 'Naura');     // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Email testing';
    $mail->Body    = 'Hi. This is  a test email.';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Email has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Email could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>

</html>
```

Comment: It's very likely that your local TLS config is broken. If you set `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and `Port = 587`, I expect you'd see it failing after `STARTTLS`. You probably need to update your CA certificate bundle. All this is described in the troubleshooting guide.

Comment: Hi. I try to update my CA. And then there some problem for update it. Do you have any other suggestion how to send email from localhost? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes - solve whatever “some problem” is.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking too much questions. My pc does not have Local Security Policy editor. So do you have suggestion on how i can  update the CA certificate?

Comment: No idea - but they are usually included in normal system updates.